# How to implement Nokia X-style UI in my app?

Tags: nokiax

My action bar app looks pretty swell on the Nokia X simulator but I want it to look and feel like the built in apps.

Some things I’m looking at in particular:

- The styling on the title bar
- The toolbar on the bottom, like in the Contacts app
- The overflow menu drawer (vs the button on the action bar)

Comment: Excellently good question (and I was not anticipating it), unfortunately there are no direct answer for it. There is no additional UI APIs for Nokia X and the Style Guide (http://developer.nokia.com/resources/library/nokia-x-ui/index.html) does not have anything on the Native application designs.

Also the layouts etc. for native apps are not published anywhere, Anyway, I'll ask other if they would know any resources.

Comment: Well the menu drawer is one I’m curious about in particular. It’s mentioned in the style guide (http://developer.nokia.com/resources/library/nokia-x-ui/porting-apps.html) but I can’t find out how to implement it that way.

Comment: Ah, I just noticed it mentions that it’s only for apps targeting Android <3.0. However all the Nokia apps do it that way.

Comment: Looks that the answer is pretty much what I wrote in the comment, which is that there is no UI offerings included in Nokia X as such, the Style guide documentation is also the only official place for any style guiding documentation for Nokia X UX designs.

Answer (score 1):

The toolbar on the bottom in e.g. contacts app is what we call "expandable option menu". It is currently not exposed to third parties at all (as we encourage apk's targeting Nokia X to remain binary compatible with vanilla AOSP apps).

The same applies for styling; we are not encouraging third party apps to adapt Nokia styling just yet, short of what they get for free (Nokia Pure font). We are collecting community feedback though; if there is good community demand for exposing the Nokia theme more widely, we can consider it for future SDK releases.